# Missing $ inserted. ^^I^^I &\square

Tags: errors, xtable

I am new to LaTeX and I am using it to write a questionnaire like this:

[image]

My current code is the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    Statement one.
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
        \square    & \square  & \square & \square 
                   & \square  & \square & \square \\
    Strongly agree & Moderately agree & Slightly agree &
Neither agree or disagree & Slightly disagree & Moderately disagree & Strongly disagree 
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
```

I got this error:

[image]

Please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\square` is a math mode construct and requires math delimiters, as in `$\square$`.  Because each field of the `tabular` is logically separate from the other fields, the math mode has to be added for each cell containing `\square`.  I also added a blank line to form the answer choices on a line of its own.

For circles, just replace `\square` with `\bigcirc`.

If **all** cells of a `tabular` are in math mode, one might preferably employ `array` instead of `tabular`, which is essentially a math-mode version of `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    Statement one.

    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
        $\bigcirc$    & $\bigcirc$  & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ 
                   & $\bigcirc$  & $\bigcirc$ & $\bigcirc$ \\
    Strongly agree & Moderately agree & Slightly agree &
Neither agree or disagree & Slightly disagree & Moderately disagree & Strongly disagree 
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. :)
Do you have any idea how can I have a circle instead of squares?

Comment: @AshKan That's easy... replace each `$\square$` with `$\bigcirc$`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the tedium of typing repeatedly `$...$`, you can use the `\Square` or `\Circle`  commands from `wasysym`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Statement one.
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c c c}
    \Square & \Square & \Square \\
    Strongly agree & Moderately agree & Slightly agree \\[2ex]
   \bfseries\Circle \\
     Neither agree or disagree \\[2ex]
     \Square & \Square & \Square \\
    Slightly disagree & Moderately disagree & Strongly disagree
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

[image]